# what kind of statement is SELECT INTO,is it DDL or DML?

Tags: sql

there is an specify remark for SELECT INTO clause,that I don't know it?is SELECT INTO a DDL or DML?I will appreciate if explain me that specify remark?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would say DML as DDL is used to define the database structure, and DML for managing data.

Select into is not different from a insert into, I belive.

Comment: I can't get this `Select into is not different from a insert into, I belive.` isn't?

Comment: `select into ...` creates a table and add data. `insert into ...` does not create a table.

Comment: OK, I did not notice it created the table, so I guess its a combination of both DML and DDL

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article on [Data manipulation language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) says (highlighting is mine):

> The SQL-data change statements are a subset of the SQL-data statements; this also contains the `SELECT` query statement, which strictly speaking is part of the DQL, not the DML. In common practice though, this distinction is not made and `SELECT` is widely considered to be part of DML, so the DML consists of all SQL-data statements, not only the SQL-data change statements. The `SELECT ... INTO ...` form combines both selection and manipulation, and thus **is strictly considered to be DML** because it manipulates (i.e. modifies) data.

Answer (score 1):

Both.  It's DDL because it changes the catalog.  It's DML because SELECT is DML.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Basically Select into is a combination query provided by microsoft from Sql server 2008 onwards to backeup data to a table, here we using DDL for creating table and DML for insertion at the definition level of SELECT INTO.